# Incorrect Value From R.dimen

Tags: android, resources

I have a dimension resource setup in my res/dimens.xml like so:

```
<dimen name="cornerRadius">40.0dp</dimen>
```

However, when I grab it into a float object like this:

```
float cornerRadius = R.dimen.cornerRadius;
```

And output the value, it gives me `2.1309686E9` every time. I'll change the value from 40.0dp to 15dp and it still outputs `2.1309686E9`.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`R.dimen.cornerRadius` is just a reference but not a value. You should use `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cornerRadius)` instead

Comment: You're right! Oops. I even had that on the line before. I guess I shouldn't have skipped my coffee this morning!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the ID not the value so try this :

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cornerRadius)
```